# SQL Subquery with two selects from different table is giving random selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Subquery with two selects from different table is giving random selection

```
select top(1) Questions.Ques_ID, Question 
from Questions 
where   Questions.Ques_ID in(
                   select   top(4)  Answers.Que_ID,Answer 
                   from Answers 
                   where  Questions.Ques_ID = Answers.Que_ID   
                   order by newid())
```

[image]

Comment: please help from this error for seeing image flows the question

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3):

When using `IN()` , same amount(and type) of elements should appear on both sides!

```
select top(1) Questions.Ques_ID, Question 
from Questions 
where   Questions.Ques_ID in(
                             select   top(4)  Answers.Que_ID 
                               from Answers 
                               where  Questions.Ques_ID = Answers.Que_ID   
                               order by newid())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems like you want to get a random Question with Matching Answers ?

```
SELECT TOP 1 ques.Ques_ID, 
             ques.Question, 
             ans.Answer
    FROM Questions ques
    INNER JOIN Answers ans ON ans.ExamCode = ques.ExamCode AND ans.Que_Id = ques.Ques_ID
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Is This What You Want?

Comment: with this question I learned something new..  ORDER BY NEWID() Can Return random records.. :D

Comment: Thanks brother you

Comment: this is what i need